# Hashable protocol for a protocol

Tags: generics, swift3, protocols, hashable, equatable

I am wondering what is wrong with the following code ?

```
import Foundation

enum SliderType: Int {
    case analog = 1, discrete, highLow
}

protocol DataEntry: class, Hashable {

    var hashValue: Int { get set } // hashable protocol requires this
    var idx: Int { get set }
    var category: String { get set }
    var sliderType: SliderType { get set }
    var sliderTitle: String { get set }
    var sliderCurrentValue: Float { get set }
    var sliderMinValue: Float { get set }
    var sliderMaxValue: Float { get set }
}

func ==(lhs: DataEntry, rhs: DataEntry) -> Bool {
    return lhs.idx == rhs.idx
}
```

As can be seen in this screenshot, I keep getting the error `Protocol 'DataEntry' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements`

Does anybody know what might be wrong here ??
How do you implement a Hashable protocol to a protocol ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`==` requires the `lhs` and `rhs` be the same type. Having both be of type `DataEntry` isn't sufficient, as you could have the `lhs` be `FooDataEntry`, and the `rhs` be `BarDataEntry`.

You need to use generics in order to enforce this relationship between `lhs` and `rhs`.

```
func ==<T: DataEntry>(lhs: T, rhs: T) -> Bool {
    return lhs.idx == rhs.idx
}
```

Comment: Hmm - still did not help. I keep getting the same error (i.e. `Protocol 'DataEntry' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements`... Could it be due to the fact that I make quite some classes conform to the `DataEntry`protocol. And these might not fall under the equatable-protocol - even with your idea of introducing generics! I guess I might have to look into making equatable work for all the classes I made conform to `DataEntry`... Or do you have any other idea ?

Comment: Pretty much wherever I use `DataEntry`such as for example inside another protocol:  `protocol BalancesModel {
 
 func getEntries(_ completionHandler: @escaping (_ entries: [DataEntry]) -> Void)
}` or inside a class, for example - where I create a property: `fileprivate var entries = [DataEntry]()`

Comment: Well yeah, that's a consequence of using protocols with Sef/associated type requirements.  Once you make `DataEntry` have a Self  type requirement (which you do indirectly my making it Equatable, which has a Self type requirement), you can only ever use it as a generic constraint

Comment: `DataEntry` isn't just one type now, it's an incomplete type. There's one version of it for every possible `Self` value it can have. Allowing you to use it directly as a type would allow you, for example, to take two different `DataEntry` subtypes and try to compare them. The equality operator is only defined for two objects of the same type, so this wouldn't be defined.

Comment: Thank you, I guess the "every possible Self" part is the tricky one, isn't it? I need to think of what I will do next. Thanks for your support!